# Set DataGridComboBoxColumn selected item

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, observablecollection, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I'm trying to set a specific item as selectedItem in a `DataGridComboBoxColumn`. However a lot of research, I couln't find the right answer for me yet.

My scenario:
I have a programatically created a `DataGrid` which has an `ObservableCollection<>` as `ItemsSource`. As a last column, I want to add a `DataGridComboBoxColumn` to give the user a selection to choose from. Since such data can already be stored in the database, I need to "preset" the value from the collection stored in the database.

```
private void ManipulateColumns(DataGrid grid)
{
    ...
    DataGridComboBoxColumn currencies = new DataGridComboBoxColumn();
    //Here come the possible choices from the database
    ObservableCollection<string> allCurrencies = new ObservableCollection<string>(Data.AllCurrencys); 
    currencies.ItemsSource = allCurrencies;
    currencies.Header = "Currency";
    currencies.CanUserReorder = false;
    currencies.CanUserResize = false;
    currencies.CanUserSort = false;
    grid.Columns.Add(currencies);
    currencies.MinWidth = 100;
    //Set the selectedItem here for the column "Currency"
    ...
}
```

I found many tutorials for setting the selected item for normal ComboBoxes, but not for DataGridComboBoxColumns. I already tried it with `currencies.SetCurrentValue()`, but I can't find a suitable `DependencyProperty` from `DataGridComboBoxColumn`.
Can someone please help me out?

Thanks in advance.
Boldi

Answer (score 0):

Building a DataGrid like that with C# code is messy. You should really take a look at using Data Binding instead. If you want to continue with building it in C#, then you are going to have to set the value per *Row*. There isn't a way to set a default for all the rows in a column. Say my DataGrid is bound to a collection of type Book. I can use the DataGrid SelectedItem property to get the Book object for the selected row, then set it's currency property. You're going to have to figure out what row you need to set the value for, get your object for that row, then set its currency property. This isn't a complete answer but it will get you started. Essentially, you are going to have to set it for each item in the DataGrid, not the column.

```
public class  Book
{
    public decimal price;
    public string title;
    public string author;
    public string currency;
}

private void ManipulateColumns(DataGrid grid)
{

    DataGridComboBoxColumn currencies = new DataGridComboBoxColumn();
    //Here come the possible choices from the database
    System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<string> allCurrencies = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<string>();
    allCurrencies.Add("US");
    allCurrencies.Add("asdf");
    allCurrencies.Add("zzz");
    currencies.ItemsSource = allCurrencies;
    currencies.Header = "Currency";
    currencies.CanUserReorder = false;
    currencies.CanUserResize = false;
    currencies.CanUserSort = false;
    grid.Columns.Add(currencies);
    currencies.MinWidth = 100;
    //Set the selectedItem here for the column "Currency"
    //currencies.

    ((Book)grid.SelectedItem).currency = "US Dollar";
}
```

Comment: Hey Brent, thanks for the reply. My goal is indeed to set a value from the combobox for every row. I'm not sure what you mean with messy though. I will try to implement this and then give feedback. But is this not the normal way to bind data to a `DataGrid`? I thought taking an `ObservableCollection` and setting it as `ItemsSource` is the right way. But I gotta admit that I'm quite new to the C#-world.